# Probability of picking card

Tags: probability, card-games

You have 2 standard decks of cards. You randomly pick 1 card from the first deck and 1 from the second. What is the probability that card from the second deck has a rank strictly higher than the rank of card picked from 1st deck?

I can define what the sample space is, but then completely stuck wih calculations. Can anyone advise me on how to do it?

Comment: Just go through the possible ranks of the second card, they are all equally probable. If the second card is a $2$, what is the probability that it is bigger?  What if it is a $3$?  And so on.  Note:  It doesn't change the final answer, but you ought to specify the rank of an Ace.

Comment: It might be faster to note that there is symmetry between the two selections.  That is, barring a tie, the two decks are equally likely to win.Thus the answer is $\frac 12\times (1-p_{tie})$.

Comment: Thank you. I now see that there is symmetry, but how to prove that it really is without going through every case?

Comment: There is an obvious bijection between the hands that win for the first deck and the hands that win for the second deck (just swap the cards).

Comment: Thanks! Now everything is clear to me.